# JQuery rotate two side back forth on hover (3D)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two side front and back. By default front is displayed, when I hover over it it display the back(ie the other side). The problem is that it returns to front by itself, what i wanted to do is unless I hover over it I want the back side to remain as it is.(Rotate back fort on hover)

Here is a live example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".cube").mouseover(function(){
        $(".cube").addClass('spin-cube');
    });
    $(".cube").mouseout(function(){
        $(".cube").removeClass('spin-cube');
    });
});
```

```css
 .wrap {
        width: 100%;
        height: 300px;
        padding-top:50px;
        clear: both;
        perspective: 800px;
        perspective-origin: 50% 100px;
    }
    .cube {
        position: relative;
        width: 200px;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .cube div {
        position: absolute;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
    }
    .left {
        background-color: #FFC250;
        transform: rotateY(270deg) translateX(-100px);
        transform-origin: center left;
    }
    .front {
        background-color: #360;
        z-index: 1000;
        transform: translateZ(100px);
    }
    @keyframes spin {
        from { transform: rotateY(0); }
        to { transform: rotateY(90deg); }
    }

    .spin-cube {
        animation: spin 2s linear;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
       <div class="cube">
          <div class="front">front</div>
          <div class="left">left</div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your code & fiddle don't match, and your problem / intentions aren't clear. Please correct your question

Comment: Sorry I was experimenting and I mess up a little bit but now I have updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solves the problem

```
  $(".cube").mouseover(function(){
        if($(".cube").hasClass("spin-cube-front")){
            $(".cube").addClass('spin-cube-back');
            $(".cube").removeClass('spin-cube-front');
        }else{
            $(".cube").removeClass('spin-cube-back');
            $(".cube").addClass('spin-cube-front');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be more easily done using a transition instead of an animation. Here is an example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var isClassy = false;
    var cooldown = false;
    $(".cube").mouseover(function(){
        if (cooldown) return;
        if (!isClassy) {
          $(".cube").addClass('spin-cube');
          isClassy = true;
        } else {
          $(".cube").removeClass('spin-cube');
          isClassy = false;
        }
        cooldown = true;
        setTimeout(function() {cooldown = false;}, 500);
    });
});
```

```css
.wrap {
        width: 100%;
        height: 300px;
        padding-top:50px;
        clear: both;
        perspective: 800px;
        perspective-origin: 50% 100px;
    }
    .cube {
        position: relative;
        width: 200px;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        margin: 0 auto;
        transition: all 1s ease;
        transform: rotateY(0deg);
    }
    .cube div {
        position: absolute;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
    }
    .left {
        background-color: #FFC250;
        transform: rotateY(270deg) translateX(-100px);
        transform-origin: center left;
    }
    .front {
        background-color: #360;
        z-index: 1000;
        transform: translateZ(100px);
    }

    .spin-cube {
        transform: rotateY(90deg);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="cube">
        <div class="front">front</div>
        <div class="left">left</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There's no reason to use Javascript/jQuery though. A simple :hover pseudo selector would work fine.

Comment: @Damien Presumably the OP is using JavaScript because he wants to be able to extend the functionality, or to integrate into an existing project. I try to give examples using the same technology used in the question - to fix examples rather than rewriting them entirely.

Comment: Ok this is good but I want the back to stay as it is unless I move my cursor out and hover it again. ie when I hover for the first time it turn to left and when I hover over it again it will turn to front. Can you get what Iam saying?

Comment: @ Maximillian Laumeister Exactly I want to do something else with it

Comment: @Puni I get what you are saying - the way I read your question it didn't seem like that's what you wanted. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: @ Maximillian Laumeister Hmm there's a little more problem (ie if i dont remove my cursor immediately it doesn't work exactly I wanted )

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".cube").mouseover(function(){
        $(".cube").addClass('spin-cube');
    });
    $(".cube").mouseout(function(){
        $(".cube").removeClass('spin-cube');
    });
});


.wrap {
        width: 100%;
        height: 300px;
        padding-top:50px;
        clear: both;
        perspective: 800px;
        perspective-origin: 50% 100px;
    }
    .cube {
        position: relative;
        width: 200px;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        margin: 0 auto;
        transition: transform 1s ease;
    }
    .cube div {
        position: absolute;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
    }
    .left {
        background-color: #FFC250;
        transform: rotateY(270deg) translateX(-100px);
        transform-origin: center left;
    }
    .front {
        background-color: #360;
        z-index: 1000;
        transform: translateZ(100px);
    }

    .spin-cube {
        transform: rotateY(90deg);
    }
```